# How to write Rewrite rule for my requirement in htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Following is the htaccess code i am using.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^admin/([a-z_]+)/?$ admin/index.php?m=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^admin/?$ admin/index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^category$ category.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)$ /user.php?username=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

When anyone visit the URL : http://www.mydomain.com/category, it should be redirected to http://www.mydomain.com/category.php. But above code is not working for my requirement.

Following line in above code is not working for me.

```
RewriteRule ^category$ category.php [L]
```

What shall i do to make it work?

Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pls explain what exactly isn't working for you?

Comment: When I copy pasted your code to my Apache it forwarded (not redirected) `/category` to `/category.php`. To test you can put a `R` flag in category rule and see your URL in browser changes to `/category.php` or not.

Comment: I tried replacing the category rule by `RewriteRule ^category$ category.php [R]` but it did not change the URL in my browser tab. The same flat is working for other forwarding rules.

Comment: You should try `RewriteRule ^category$ category.php [R,L]` and if that doesn't work post relevant log snippet from access.log and error.log in your question.

Comment: Still not working. It is giving me `404 not found` error even though the file `category.php` file does exist on the server and i can check it with the URL `http://www.mydomain.com/category.php`. Even when i set `R` flag, its not changing anything in the URL.

Comment: That was not meant to be fix anyway, it was just a test. Are you sure your .htaccess is in effect. Try putting some garbage text at top of your file and see if throws 500 error or not?

Comment: If i put garbage values in .htaccess file it is giving me `500 Internal server error`. Also, in above code, the Rewriterule `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)$ /user.php?username=$1 [L]` works perfect for me.

Comment: Ok good to know, can you post your full .htaccess in your question. Also post relevant snippets from your access.log and error.log as well.